# Is partitioning helpful in Amazon Athena if query doesn't filter based on partition?

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, presto

I have a large amount of data, but there is no particular column I would like to filter based on (that is, my 'where clause' can be any column). In this scenario, does partitioning provide any benefit (maybe helps with read-parallelism?) when the queries end up scanning all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no column all, or most, queries would filter on then partitions will only hurt performance. Instead aim for files around 100 MB, as few as possible, Parquet if possible, and put all files directly under the table's `LOCATION`.

The reason why partitions would hurt performance is that when Athena starts executing your query it will list all files, and the way it does it is as if S3 was a file system. It starts by listing the table's `LOCATION`, and if it finds anything that looks like a directory it will list it separately, and so on, recursively. If you have a deep directory structure this can end up taking a lot of time. You want to help Athena by having all your files in a flat structure, but also fewer than 1000 of them, because that's the page size for S3's list operation. With more than 1000 files you want to have directories so that Athena can parallelize the listing (but as few as possible still, because there's a limit to how many listings it will do in parallel).

You want to keep file sizes to around 100 MB because that's a good size that trades off how long it takes to process a file against the overhead of getting it from S3. [The exact recommendation is 128 MB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/).

Comment: Is there a benefit from Parquet over ORC when Athena is concerned? For long, Presto's ORC implementation was more performant, but it might be that Athena has some changes in this space.

Comment: Unless Amazon made extensive changes to Presto for Athena, that isn't true.  Presto delays loading partition detail and file listing until the query starts execution, and then it does this in parallel streaming fashion.  We specifically designed Presto this way to avoid this startup latency.  Partitioning can help reduce latency, because it can force more splits, which can mean more parallelism in the scans.  Again this all depend on exactly which changes Amazon made to Presto when building Athena.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I haven't done any strict benchmarks, but for our workloads we have seen better performance with Parquet, plus Parquet supports schema evolution better (e.g. adding a column is ok with Parquet, not ok with ORC). One specific thing we've seen is that Athena seems to always read the full ORC file, even when you select only a single column, but not so with Presto.

Comment: @DainSundstrom you obviously know a lot more about the details than I do, and I didn't mean my description above to be definitive. From a very high level I think your description and mine aren't that dissimilar. In my experience with Athena S3 operations dominate the execution time for queries that take seconds to run.

Comment: "Athena seems to always read the full ORC file" -- that's weird. I didn't know that. Presto doesn't have such limitation.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I found it odd too, but in my experiments I've gotten the same value for `DataScannedInBytes` for `SELECT a FROM …` and `SELECT a, b FROM …` and so on. The same has not been true for Parquet. I haven't done any extensive testing, because Parquet has been more convenient to use for other reasons, but I was surprised when I did compare them.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not crazy I re-ran a Parquet vs ORC experiment. I used CTAS to create two tables from the same source data, one in Parquet format one in ORC. No partitioning, bucketing, just the defaults. `SELECT a FROM test_pq WHERE x = 'theo'` scans 44 MB, `SELECT * FROM test_pq WHERE x = 'theo'` scans 456 MB, `SELECT a FROM test_orc WHERE x = 'theo'` scans 99 MB, `SELECT * FROM test_orc WHERE x = 'theo'` scans 99 MB. The ORC data got much better default compression, but both queries scanned the same amount of data. There may factors that make this an unfair test that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Another interesting test: `SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM test_pq` scans 96 KB, `SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM test_orc` scans 600 MB. That's over 6000x the data. The query engine can clearly make much better use of the metadata of Parquet files for some queries. The opposite may be true for other queries that I have not tested, though, and this is a very limited test.

Comment: There was a bug in Presto that caused massive over read for S3 it was fixed somewhere around version 303.  The two follow tests you have show some other differences in the code.  IIRC the parquet reader in Presto will aggressively read dictionaries to do skipping.  This can be a big win in some cases and a big loss in others if the column ends up not being needed.  I’m not sure what you are doing in the last one as since there is a missing group by clause.  One important thing to note is the Presto Parquet reader is based on the ORC reader code, so they should not be dramatically different.

Comment: That explains a lot, I've been looking at the S3 operations that Athena is making for a query and they are not what you would want it to do. It treats S3 as a file system with directories and files. For unpartitioned tables listing "directories" recursively could be very costly compared to just listing the keys. Athena is based on 0.172, and I don't think they have done a lot about those things. The last example was just be missing the `GROUP BY` when I wrote it here, these boxes are so tiny it's easy to miss things.